# Android Activities to Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to design my application and running into some problems. In the beginning stages I was coding everything in different activities to make sure every thing worked. Now that everything does work I am moving to the design. I am trying to use fragments in replace of the activities.

My issues is copying the code from the activity into a fragment, when I do so I am faced with countless errors, things like `findViewById` not working and other functions that seems to be focused towards activities not working when moved to a fragment.

Is there a migration technique that I can use to change from activities to fragments? Or do I have to change each of the functions and errors to suit the new fragments?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, ill have a look at those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no migration technique for this. You will have to manually resolve all the errors you are getting. As a general idea you can do this.

1. Wherever you are using `findViewById`, now you need to do `view.findViewbyId(R.id.view_id);`, where `view` is the inflated view inside the `Fragment`.
2. Any functionality which is focused towards or using context of `Activity` should be prefixed with `getActivity()`.
3. Wherever you are using `this` or something like `MyActivity.this`, you should replace it with `getActivity()`.

Comment: @JJSmith: Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Look up a basic tutorial in Google or YouTube on how to use `Fragments` and what's the difference to `Activities` as a start...

For example, the `findViewById` error is because in your fragment's `onCreateView` method, after you inflate the layout for your fragment which would look something like this:

```
View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_host, container, false);
```

you need to use the findVyewById method using this `fragmentView` we just initiated. Like that:

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

If working with `Fragments`, often a `NavigationDrawer` is a great component to use (The one with the hamburger icon in your `Toolbar`). To implement that, look up a tutorial on the new `NavigationView` and the `DrawerLayout`. You'd need the `design support library` for that but this will be explained in the tutorial. In the layout xml for your main activity that is hosting this `DrawerLayout`, you'd have a `FrameLayout` where you'd put your fragments which are your app's content.

Comment: excellent thanks for the advice Ill have a look through some more docs